# Возможно ли в цикле менять обрабатываемые переменные?

Tags: python, переменные

У меня есть несколько списков со списками оборудования оргтехники. Эти списки набираются произвольным пользовательским образом, но изначально все они имеют список-заголовок, идущий первым для формирования таблицы. Одному списку соответствует один отдел компании.

```
department_list = ['Бухгалтерия', 'Производство', 'Колл-центр', 'HR', 'Склад', 'Списано']
header = ['Название', 'Тип оборудования', 'Количество', 'Цена за штуку']
accountance = [header]
production = [header]
callcentre = [header]
HR = [header]
warehouse = [header]
writeoff = [header]
```

Изначально все оборудование попадает на склад, а затем распределяется по отделам. У меня получилось написать код для перемещения в один конкретный отдел:

```
def distribute(self, name, department, amount):
    distribution = [name, amount]
    if department == 'Бухгалтерия':
        for el in Warehouse.accountance:
            if distribution in el[:-1]:
                p = el[-1]
                a = el[-2]
                Warehouse.accountance.append([name, a + amount, p])
                Warehouse.accountance.remove(el)
                Warehouse.warehouse.append([name, el[-2] - amount, el[-1]])
                Warehouse.warehouse.remove(el)
            else:
                for el in Warehouse.warehouse:
                    if distribution in el[:-1]:
                        Warehouse.accountance.append([name, amount, el[-1]])
                        Warehouse.warehouse.append([name, el[-2] - amount, el[-1]])
                        Warehouse.warehouse.remove(el)
                    else: print('Ошибка: такого оборудования нет на складе!')
```

Я не хочу повторять этот код для всех отделов, но как - не понимаю. Есть ли у python возможность сделать какой-то псевдоним для переменной? Например, при вызове функции записать: 'Колл-центр' и она поймет, что надо обрабатывать переменную callcentre?

Comment: Это у вас функция класса? а как вы ее вызываете?

Answer (score 1):

Загнать все ваши отделы в словарь. И работать с ним по именам отделов.

```
department_list = ['Бухгалтерия', 'Производство', 'Колл-центр', 'HR', 'Склад', 'Списано']
header = ['Название', 'Тип оборудования', 'Количество', 'Цена за штуку']
departments = {k:[header] for k in department_list}

def distribute(self, name, department, amount):
    distribution = [name, amount]
    for el in Warehouse.departments[department]:
        if distribution in el[:-1]:
            p = el[-1]
            a = el[-2]
            Warehouse.departments[department].append([name, a + amount, p])
            Warehouse.departments[department].remove(el)
            Warehouse.departments['Склад'].append([name, el[-2] - amount, el[-1]])
            Warehouse.departments['Склад'].remove(el)
        else:
            for el in Warehouse.departments['Склад']:
                if distribution in el[:-1]:
                    Warehouse.departments[department].append([name, amount, el[-1]])
                    Warehouse.departments['Склад'].append([name, el[-2] - amount, el[-1]])
                    Warehouse.departments['Склад'].remove(el)
                else: print('Ошибка: такого оборудования нет на складе!')
```

Можно передать и переменную через аргумент функции. В вашем случае будет работать, т.к. у вас там списки, а они mutable.